# Python: Move files from Folder and subfolders to another similar directory

Tags: python

I have two source file paths:

```
C:\Same\Path\To\File\unknown\
C:\Same\Path\To\File\unrecognized\
```

And one destination path:

```
C:\Same\Path\To\File\Import
```

The subfolders for all these paths are the same. They are 10-15 folders that have 3 digit names (233 for example).

If any files are in these subfolders of the source paths I want to CUT them from that directory and send them to the destination directory with the same path as the source. i am new to python so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is [`shutil.move`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) ([py3k docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)):

```
Help on function move in module shutil:

move(src, dst)
Recursively move a file or directory to another location. This is
similar to the Unix "mv" command.

If the destination is a directory or a symlink to a directory, the source
is moved inside the directory. The destination path must not already
exist.

If the destination already exists but is not a directory, it may be
overwritten depending on os.rename() semantics.

If the destination is on our current filesystem, then rename() is used.
Otherwise, src is copied to the destination and then removed.
A lot more could be done here...  A look at a mv.c shows a lot of
the issues this implementation glosses over.
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) module.